# getting syntax error from nifi ExecuteScript processor inspite of correct python code

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, regex, apache-nifi

I am getting below error inspite of correct python code don't know how to resolve this error. Any help is much appreciated

```
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: SyntaxError: no viable alternative at input '*' in <script> at line number 35 at column number 26
```

python code

```
def get_match_list(regEx, line):
    match = re.search(regEx, line)
    print(match)
    if match:
        match_list = [*match.groups()] # this is the line exception is pointed
        return match_list
    else:
        return []
```

Comment: Could you please provide input that makes it error in your question that

Comment: is that '*' not recognized/parsed as valid identifier by nifi processor? or input error?

Comment: Try use list(match.groups) instead of [*match.groups], let me know if it not worked

Comment: it worked after changing to list(match.groups) thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

It looks like jython [use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jython#Status_and_roadmap) python 2.7 and as [Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) is a feature that introduced in python 3.5 you can not use this syntax in jython, so an alternative way to convert a tuple to a list is that use `list ( match.groups)` it works fine in older versions of python and current version of jython (2.7.2)

Comment: @SahilSaxena Your welcome, consider that if this answer helps you accept this answer by click on ✔